# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionDuration' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

Getting message in console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionDuration' of undefined jquery.masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2:11

```
var container = jQuery('.row-container');

container.imagesLoaded(container, function () {
    container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.article',
        isAnimated: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: check all js files which linked

Comment: Find first where in which file/code you have "transitionDuration" is defined or used? there must be some object via it this property has been set, and that object would be null so thats why you getting such error

Comment: @Rupal It has come from my code snippet.

Comment: @SagarKodte linked only latest masonry.

Answer (score 1):

Here used option `isAnimated` has been removed from latest [Masonry](https://github.com/desandro/masonry).

[Refer @desandro comment](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/183#issuecomment-19437176)

Will use [transitionDuration](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#transitionduration) for transition in latest [Masonry](https://github.com/desandro/masonry).

**UPDATED**

You can check how transition works at here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshwaghmare/gkv8o7yf/1/)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Yes but where and how you are using transitionduration property in your code, you should show it here, so other can look and try to find exact reason and resolution for an issue.

Comment: @Rupal I was removed transition from my code. But, To know how transition works? Updated answer by adding jsfiddle URL with screenshot for reference.

Comment: Your code is correct, I have created page with your provided fiddle in my machine and all works fine for me without the JS error which you currently facing